# FileNotFoundException - java

Tags: java, xml, swing, parsing, filenotfoundexception

I am Using SAX Parser But after debugging the error is shown at this line

```
saxParser.parse("C:\\Sample.XML", handler);
```

Error is:- `java.io.FileNotFoundException`: C:\Sample.XML (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: So, does the file exist? Is it readable?

Comment: Are you sure you really have a file at C:\ called Sample.XML ?

Comment: the exception itself tells you the solution put your file in the right path.

Comment: Java may not have permission to read the file

Comment: It is in readable format as well as i have copied the link from address bar and pasted it over and above i have tried changing with the Caption with capital and backslash but still did not worked. I am using Jbuilder

Comment: If you are using Windows Vista or above, Java may not be allowed to read from the root drive.  Try placing it some where else, like your documents folder

Comment: I am using xp and jbuilder as compiler

Comment: Try something simpler.  Start with `System.out.println(new File("C:\\Sample.XML").exists());` to see if Java can see it and opening the file with something like a `FileInputStream` to see if you can actually read it...

Comment: @MadPrgrammer it is returning false statement. Is there any permission needed to give to the compiler to access the file.  The attributes of file are not ticked so that they can read and write them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash "\" is the escape character in a java string.

You need to double escape the backslash "\\".

If in doubt consult the [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: "\\" escapes the escape character, allowing it to be used like this (do it all the time).  Alternatively the OP could use "/" instead, but I can't see it making any difference

Comment: Not sure if this answer is valid after OP was edited!

Comment: I see, that's mean of them, don't you hate that ;)